# Elasticsearch transform on search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I've an issue with data in my Elastic index where certain string fields contain differing values that should be the same. For example X-Box, X Box and XBox.

I realise that I could add some transforms to my mappings, but it's not really appropriate in the case as we have data coming in from many sources and the values are unknown until we have received them.

Is it possible to define something like a transform but on search? For example, user searches 'XBox' but because we have defined it (after having discovered the variances) Elastic knows to also return documents for 'X-Box and XBox'?

Hope that makes sense? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Synonym filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) is what you are looking for. It can map variants to a common name. 
You can refer to this [blog](http://blog.qbox.io/qbox-elasticsearch-tutorial-episode-3) for creating analyzer.
Just use the format as shown below -

```
{
    "filter" : {
        "synonym" : {
            "type" : "synonym",
            "synonyms" : [
                "X-box, x box => xbox",
                "universe, cosmos"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking I define this on my index as opposed to with each search?

Comment: Yes , certainly while index time. You need to sent this as part of mapping.